# OOPs approach in javascript to create DOM nodes

Tags: javascript, oop

I am not clear about how to use OOPs approach in Javascript. As a practice, i am designing a to-do list (only client side - HTML, javascript for now, to practice javascript. No server side code or interaction).

On HTML page, i have a button "Add Item", which will dynamically create and insert an element with some child elements

```
<body>
   <button type="button" onclick="addNewItem()">Add New Item</button>
   <div id="todolist" class="todolistBody">
          <!-- Sample node that javascript function addNewItem() should add 
            <div id="item1" class="listItem">
                <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" onchange="itemChecked()">
                <input id="inputText1" type="text" name="">
                <button type="button" id="removeButton1" onclick="removeItem()">Remove</button>
            </div>
            -->
   </div>
</body>
```

currently i am doing whole Document.createElement thing in the javascript file

```
function addNewItem(){
    var listDiv = document.createElement("div");
    listDiv.className = "listItem";
    var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
    checkBox.type="checkbox";
    checkBox.onchange = itemChecked;
    var textBox = document.createElement("input");
    textBox.type = "text";
    textBox.name = "";
    var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
    removeButton.type="button";
    removeButton.innerHTML="Delete";
    removeButton.onclick= removeItem;
    listDiv.appendChild(checkBox);
    listDiv.appendChild(textBox);
    listDiv.appendChild(removeButton);
    var element = document.getElementById("todolist");
    element.appendChild(newListItem);
}
```

and there are variable methods named removeItem and itemChecked as well.

Now that whole node that gets dynamically inserted into HTML, i was wondering if it can be a class (like in java), say listItem and somehow, in javascript all i have to do is

```
var newListItem = new listItem();
var element = document.getElementById("todolist");
element.appendChild(newListItem);
```

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: what is `itemChecked`

Comment: Note that using inline event handlers is bad practice and results in poorly factored, hard-to-manage code. Seriously consider attaching your events with JavaScript, instead, eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener

Comment: Also, what is `newListItem` on the last line? It's not defined in your code yet, but it seems to be the whole point of it.

Comment: Actually what you are currently doing **is** an OOP approach. You have an element factory that creates an instance of let's call it class HTMLElement

Answer (score 0):

Just return the element you are creating inside your function, that allows you to use `new listItem()`. Attach the event handler programmatically using `addEventListener` instead of `onlick`.

```js
function listItem() {
  var listDiv = document.createElement("div");
  listDiv.className = "listItem";
  var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
  checkBox.type = "checkbox";
  // checkBox.onchange = itemChecked;
  var textBox = document.createElement("input");
  textBox.type = "text";
  textBox.name = "";
  var removeButton = document.createElement("button");
  removeButton.type = "button";
  removeButton.innerHTML = "Delete";
  // removeButton.onclick= removeItem;
  listDiv.appendChild(checkBox);
  listDiv.appendChild(textBox);
  listDiv.appendChild(removeButton);
  return listDiv;
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var newListItem = new listItem();
  todolist.appendChild(newListItem);
})
```

```html
<button type="button">Add New Item</button>
<div id="todolist" class="todolistBody">
  <!-- Sample node that javascript function addNewItem() should add 
            <div id="item1" class="listItem">
                <input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" onchange="itemChecked()">
                <input id="inputText1" type="text" name="">
                <button type="button" id="removeButton1" onclick="removeItem()">Remove</button>
            </div>
            -->
</div>
```